If you hold a pendulum and make it move in a circle, is that termed rotation?
What is the correct term to describe circular movement of a hand held pendulum? If you hold a pendulum that is hanging from a string and then force the pendulum to make circular motions, is that motion called rotation? What is the correct "lay term" for this type of movement? Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What you are describing is a conical pendulum.

Thanks. What is the English vocab word to describe a conical pendulums movement? Is it rotation, or spin?

@user436660 Rotation is better. Spin usually denotes an object rotating about its own centre of mass. In this case you could say that the pendulum bob is rotating about the axis of the cone swept out by its string.
